# How to get only the date from a DateTime object?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a variable of type DateTime() and I want to get only the date of it to compare it with an other date variable. Here is how I tried to do that, but I get extra data that I don't need:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Tunis');
$date= new \DateTime('today');
$date->format('d/m/Y');
```

`var_dump($date)` returns : `object(DateTime)#617 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2017-04-09 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Africa/Tunis" }`
So I want to get something like this : 09/04/2017

UPDATE: This is my action code (I have a form in twig that contains a date type input) :

```
 public function addArtAction(Request $request)
    {

        $article=new article();
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $title=$request->request->get('titre');
        $content=$request->files->get('contenu');
        $dtePub=$request->request->get('date');
        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Tunis');
        $datee= new \DateTime('today');
        $date=$datee->format('d/m/Y');

        if($dtePub==$date)
        {
            $article->setTitre($title);
            $article->setCorps($content);
            $article->setEtat(true);
            $article->setDtePub($date);
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success','Votre article a été archivé!');
        }
        elseif($dtePub>$date)
        {
        $article->setTitre($title);
        $article->setCorps($content);
        $article->setEtat(false);
        $article->setDteArch($date);
        $article->setDtePub($dtePub);
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success','Votre article a été publié avec succès!');
        }
        elseif($dtePub<$date)
        {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('failure','Vous devez choisir une future date!');
        }
        var_dump($date);

    }
```

Comment: `$date->format(..)` returns a string with a formatted date.

Comment: [PHP doesn't use MS Excel format masks for dates](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).... reading the docs always helps

Comment: Please stop adding `symfony` tag, your question has nothing to do with symfony.

Comment: Please remove the big code block you added in the last update, it does not help clarify the question in any way. The time of your fellow users is valuable, this is waste.

Answer (score 7):

You were doing it (almost right). For reference here a copy-paste your code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Tunis');
$date= new \DateTime('today');
$date->format('d/m/Y');
```

The last line returns the desired string. If you want to output that you can just `echo` it:

```
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Basically your misunderstanding was that the `format` method does not modify the `$date` object, but only return the desired string. If you look at [the documentation for the `format` method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) you will find:

> Returns date formatted according to given format

It says "returns" with which means returned to the context of the call: the expression of the call 'is substituted' by the returned value. If it would output it in the function, then the manual would have said something like "prints" or "outputs" or "dumps". You can read more about what 'returning a value' means in [this part of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php). The first example shows the exact equivalent of what you tried to do:

> Example #1 Use of return
>
> ```
> <?php function square($num) {
>   return $num * $num;
> }
> echo square(4);   // outputs '16'.
> ?>
> ```

Lastly, with regards to the use of `var_dump`: please note that this is intended for debugging purposes and normally not for displaying output to the user. `var_dump` will normally just dump "All public, private and protected properties of objects" of the given object. You should check [the `var_dump` manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) it contains many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use format:

```
$date->format('d/m/Y');
```

or

```
$date->format('m/d/Y');
```

(I don't know your locale preferences)

Comment: "What do you want to do?" --- "So I want to get something like this : 09/04/2017".

Comment: i've tried date() methode : it needs a string $date passed to it like this : date($date, $timestamp)

Comment: format('d/m/Y') doesn't change anything : i told i want to get only the date, doesn't matter if its 09-04-2017 or 09/04/2017

Comment: Susan, not `date()` but: `$date = new \DateTime('now'); echo $date->format('m/d/Y');`

Comment: @Susan `date()` has nothing to do with DateTime objects (other than the format mask values are the same), because `date()` only works with unix timestamps

Comment: @LeonidZakharov this is almost what I've written: you only changed the format('m/d/Y')

Comment: @Susan and your question now is... ? :-)

Comment: Please understand me: var_dump($date) returns a variable that contains : Date and Time and TimeZone, but I want to only get the date ONLYYY , to compare it to a date variable

Comment: @Susan Because you need to deal with what `date->format` returns, since the `format` method does not modify the date object in any way: `$formattedDate = $date->format('d/m/Y'); var_dump($formattedDate);`

Comment: @zerkms okay i changed my code to this $datee= new \DateTime('today');
 $date=$datee->format('d/m/Y'); But I got an error : Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: @Susan `$datee= new \DateTime('today'); $date=$datee->format('d/m/Y'); ` - this code totally works http://ideone.com/Bqa0ZP. It is something else that you broke.

Comment: no the problem is caused by the date; because before adding the date type field, everything was working pretty good

Comment: Please show the complete code, it's not obvious what problem you have at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. And now more questions: do you realise that after you formatted a date with `date->format` it's not a datetime object anymore, but a string. Which means that the `$dtePub>$date` comparison makes very little sense, since `$date` is a string... Also now `$article->setDtePub($date);` would likely to fail since they likely to expect a datetime object.

Comment: Ah var_dump confused me because its output was FAKE : so when i displayed the variable $date in my twig template i found out that its a string : 10/04/2017

Comment: @zerkms so how can I compare $date to a date type object??

Comment: I think I should use the diff() method without using format() that transforms the date type object to string

Comment: Why cannot you just compare datetime objects, why do you need to format it first? Now you may see: you have not explained the original problem, just your unsuccessful attempt. Then we spent an hour trying to fix something that is likely to be incorrect from the very beginning.

Comment: i tried this : $interval=$date->diff($dtePub);but I got this warning :Warning: DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, integer given. So i used strToTime()::::   $interval=$date->diff(strtotime($dtePub)); but still I have the same warning!!!!

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't know the output It get from var_dump i wasn't the true output!! that's what made me think that way

Comment: Yes i deleted the format(), I don't need it anymore; but the problem now is that the datetime variable i get it from a datetype input field is a string

Comment: `$date = new \DateTime($dateFromInput);`

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compare to another date timestamp just convert it like this:

```
<?php
  $literal = "1 week ago";
  $date = new DateTime($literal);
  $date->setTime(0,0);

  $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wondered "**How to get only the date from a DateTime object**?"

Just for fun :

```
explode(" ",get_object_vars(new DateTime())["date"])[0]
```

returns (**for today only**): 2023-05-15

Answer (score -4):

you can try the strtotime function:
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));

Comment: I am sure she can try a lot of things, but this suggestion does not help her. I am sure that is why you received all these down votes.

Comment: Thank you for comment Paul it was really helpful .. I m not a programmer, I ve started 4 months to coding as a hobby. I found a lot of help on that forum so I thought to try to give an idea in order to help..The truth is that I m a little bit disappointed about all this because It was just my first post. I suppose I have to be an expert before I try to tell an idea again ...no worries cheers :)

Comment: Haha, no worries. I can imagine it is a bit demotivating. Feel free to ask for feedback. I would definitely advise you to keep trying, but keep respectfull to the time of the hundreds or thousands that might be reading your text: do truly your very best to give the most helpfull answer to the OP and all other readers. Try to understand the question. Do research, if you are not 100% sure test your code. I recently posted some answers quickly from my phone during a short metro ride. Those received some well deserved downvotes :) lesson learned. I deleted the posts. Thanks for your effort! Cheers

Comment: Thank you man really for the time you spent to give me that advices.. I understand now that s the correct way to help and be better in the same time :) .. Thanx ;)